# Check between two columns in two different tables in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have two tables named as `ITEM_DETAILS` AND `SALES` in my database both of them have `QUANTITY` columns.

I want to make a check that my `SALES.QUANTITY` table becomes dependent on `ITEM_DETAILS.QUANTITY` and I want the check that if `ITEM_DETAILS.QUANTITY` is zero than it does not allow me to SALE any `QUANTITY` from `SALES.QUANTITY`.

How I could do that?

I have a check constraint on :

```
ITEM_DETAILS.QUANTITY>=0
```

but how sales quantity will become dependent on this?

Comment: How do you relate item_details and sales, other than by quantity?

Comment: You need to post the structure or the relation between your tables

Comment: Item_model in Item_details is primary key and foreign key in sales